# eventTimeFormat not working in my fullcalendar library version 4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, lwc

I'm using a fullcalendar library inside a Salesforce lwc. I need to set the 24 hours format to my timegrid view as now its shown as 3pm, 4pm, etc. I tried adding the eventTimeFormat but it doesn't work. Also tried with the deprecated timeFormat :D. Show you my code if it could help :)

```
// imports ...
import fullcalendar from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullcalendar";

export default class WeeklyWorkSummaryFullCalendar extends LightningElement {
    calendar;
    fullCalendarInitialized = false;
    consultantId;
    deliveryProjects;
    eventsData = [];

    @api weekView;
    @api dayView;
    @api listView;
    @track
    calendarLabel;

    @wire(getConsultantCoachingProjectsForYear)
    wiredConsultantSolutionsForYear({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.deliveryProjects = data;
            this.eventsData = data.map(project => {
                // go through the data for events
            });
            this.calendar.addEventSource(this.eventsData);
            console.log(this.eventsData);
            this.calendar.render();
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener('fceventclick', this.handleEventClick.bind(this));
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.fullCalendarInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.fullCalendarInitialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/core/main.js"),
            loadStyle(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/core/main.css"),
        ])
            .then(() => {
                // got to load core first, then plugins
                Promise.all([
                    loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.js"),
                    loadStyle(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.css"),
                    loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/list/main.js"),
                    loadStyle(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/list/main.css"),
                    loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.js"),
                    loadStyle(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.css"),
                    loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/interaction/main.js"),
                    loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/moment/main.js"),
                    loadScript(this, fullcalendar + "/packages/moment-timezone/main.js"),
                ]).then(() => {
                    console.log("Library Initialized!");
                    this.init();
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error", error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error loading FullCalendar",
                        variant: "error"
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    init() {
        var calendarEl = this.template.querySelector(".calendar");
        this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            header: false,
            plugins: ["dayGrid", "list", "timeGrid", "interaction", "moment", "moment-timezone"],
            defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
            firstDay: 1,
            allDay: false,
            hour12: false
        });

        this.calendar.render();
        this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
    }

}
```

[image]

Expecting the hour format to change to 24 hour format.

Comment: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) article from the help centre is also relevant. Once you've added an answer properly, you should also roll back the edit you've made to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** My timegrid view is working now with the 24 hour format. I was wrongly setting the eventTimeFormat (as this is just for events). What worked for me was slotLabelFormat. Show you the solution :)

```
    header: false,
    plugins: ["dayGrid", "list", "timeGrid", "interaction", "moment", "moment-timezone"],
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    firstDay: 1,
    minTime: '00:00:00',
    maxTime: '21:00:00',
    slotLabelFormat: { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false }
```